# AngularJs and Bootstrap : Progress bar and Pop over issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

currently in my xhtml page iam displaying both Popover on click of a  button
and also tile view with a progress bar in it.
But when i used the below code

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
```

**ProgressBar** is displaying but **POPOver** is not working. and

when i used the below code

```
<script src="/cg510_claimsdb_lib/ext/bootstrap-3.1.1/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
```

**POPOver** is displaying but **ProgressBar** is not working.

**ProgressBar code :**

```
 <uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active" value="dynamic" type="info">info <i ng-show="showWarning">!!! Watch out !!!</i></uib-progressbar>
```

**POPOver code :**

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="margin-left: 20px;" popover-placement="right" popover-template="'/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/listFilter.xhtml'" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}"  aria-hidden="true"
       popover-elem="true"></button>
```

I am totally confused on this.

Comment: add some code how you have tried to have popover & progress bar..

Comment: Hi Pankaj, sample code added.

Comment: Problem resolved, by the follow code                                                                                      <button uib-popover-template="'/cg510_claimsdb_main/html/listFilter.xhtml'" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" 
     class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="margin-left: 20px;" popover-placement="right"  aria-hidden="true"
     type="button" popover-elem="true" ></button>